# I am having an issue accessing the scope of my controller from my directive Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, dom-events

I can't get to my settings that I am getting from the server, I have my app set up and my directives are working. I am using `$http` to get a js file from the server that has a bunch of settings for my app the request is being sent from the controller of my directive, but I can't get to the scope when I do a `console.log(scope)` it shows me my scope but when I try to access the objects within my scope from the directive I just get a null value?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="uploader">
   <head>
     <title></title>
     <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="Scripts/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
     <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
     <script src="app/uploader.js"></script>
 <style>

    html, body { margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; background-color:#e3e3e3; }

</style>
</head>
  <body dropzone='{"url":"app/settings.js"}'>

 </body>
</html>
```

my app/uploader.js file

```
var app = angular.module("uploader", []);

app.directive('dropzone', function () {

return {

    restrict: "A",
    controller: function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.getSettings = function (url) {

            $http.get(url).then(function (response) {

                $scope.settings = response.data;
                //console.log($scope.settings);
            });

        }

    },
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {

        var settings = JSON.parse(attr.dropzone);
        scope.getSettings(settings.url);
        console.log(element);
        console.log(attr);
        console.log(scope);
        
        function handleDragEnter(e) {

            console.log(e)
            //console.log(scope.settings);
        }

        function handleDragOver(e) {

            console.log(e)
            //console.log(scope.settings);
            
            
        } function handleDrop(e) {

            console.log(e)
            //console.log(scope.settings);

        }

        element.bind('dragenter', handleDragEnter);
        element.bind('dragover', handleDragOver);
        element.bind('drop', handleDrop);
        console.log(scope.settings);

    }

}

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `$scope.getSettings()` is asynchronous, `$scope.settings` might not have been set by the time the event happens.  You might update the `link` function to wait until the call finishes before actually bind the event.

```
link: function (scope, element, attr) {
    var settings = JSON.parse(attr.dropzone);
    scope.getSettings(settings.url).then(function() {
        function handleDragEnter(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
        function handleDragOver(e) {
            console.log(e)
        } 
        function handleDrop(e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
        element.bind('dragenter', handleDragEnter);
        element.bind('dragover', handleDragOver);
        element.bind('drop', handleDrop);
        console.log(scope.settings);
    });
}
```

Also, update `getSettings` to return a promise.

```
$scope.getSettings = function (url) {
    return $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
        $scope.settings = response.data;
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! I didn't understand the whole concept of promises and scopes. I really appreciate your help thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I have a little more studying to do with Angular particularly the abstraction of elements and events